# ¿Cómo aclarar fondo al abrir modal Bootstrap?

Tags: html, bootstrap, css3, modal

Tengo un botón donde al dar clic se abre un modal de Bootstrap, dicho modal aparece, pero se quedaba con fondo oscuro y la pantalla se bloqueaba, esto lo pude resolver con CSS con la siguiente lineal de código:

```
.modal {
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;
z-index: 1050;
display: none;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
overflow: hidden;
outline: 0;
  }
```

Todo funciona correctamente pero se ve muy oscuro el fondo, lo que quiero es aclarar dicho fondo, para esto utilice opacity del mínimo pero no me funciono, también ponerle fondo blanca y opacity pero no di con el objetivo.

Este es mi modal:

```
<div class="container">
  <h2>Basic Modal Example</h2>
  <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
    
      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Estos son los link que estableci:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

El resultado de esto es el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me podrían orientar en como resolver este problema por favor, cualquier comentario es de gran ayuda. Gracias.

Comment: Cuando miraste el manual de boostrap lo hiciste demasiado rápido, todo esto que pides esta explicado en en mismo manual y lo puedes hacer con etiquetas, sin necesitad de añadir código propio

Comment: Gracias, le voy a echar un vistazo,  Gracias.

Comment: Cuando lo mires puedes autoresponderte y así quien tenga la misma duda encontrará esto. También puedes responder aquí usando @ y le puedo pegar un vistazo (si quieres, claro)